# net::ERR_CERT_INVALID using Go backend

Tags: go, ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I am currently having an API running on `:443` as you can see below:

```
// RunAsRESTAPI runs the API as REST API
func (api *API) RunAsRESTAPI(restAddr string) error {

    // Generate a `Certificate` struct
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair( ".certificates/my-domain.crt", ".certificates/my-domain.key" )
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("couldn't load the X509 certificates: %v\n", err))
    }

    // create a custom server with `TLSConfig`
    restAPI := &http.Server{
        Addr: restAddr,
        Handler: nil, // use `http.DefaultServeMux`
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
            Certificates: []tls.Certificate{ cert },
        },
    }

    // Defining the routes
    routes := map[string]func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request){
        "": api.handleIndex,
    }

    // Initialize mux
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    // Register endpoints handlers
    for route, function := range routes {
        endpoint := "/" + route
        mux.HandleFunc(endpoint, function)
        log.Printf("[%s] endpoint registered.\n", endpoint)
    }

    // cors.Default() setup the middleware with default options being
    // all origins accepted with simple methods (GET, POST). See
    // documentation below for more options.
    restAPI.Handler = cors.Default().Handler(mux)

    log.Printf("REST TLS Listening on %s\n", restAddr)
    return restAPI.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")
}
```

I created my certificates like so:

```
$ openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout my-domain.key -out my-domain.csr
$ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in my-domain.csr -signkey my-domain.key -out my-domain.crt
```

I then dockerized, then deployed to Google Compute Engine, but, I am still getting this `net::ERR_CERT_INVALID` while requesting my API from a ReactJs App (Google Chrome)

I have no issues on Postman.. I don't understand, it even says that `this certificate has not been verified by a third party`

I am a bit lost, to be honest, how can I solve this? So my app can request my HTTPS backend

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. I actually found a way to make it work in a SUPER EASY WAY:

```
func (api *API) RunAsRESTAPI() error {

    // Defining the routes
    routes := map[string]func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request){
        "": api.handleIndex,
    }

    // Initialize mux
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    // Register endpoints handlers
    for route, function := range routes {
        endpoint := "/" + route
        mux.HandleFunc(endpoint, function)
        log.Printf("[%s] endpoint registered.\n", endpoint)
    }

    // cors.Default() setup the middleware with default options being
    // all origins accepted with simple methods (GET, POST). See
    // documentation below for more options.
    handler := cors.Default().Handler(mux)

    log.Printf("REST TLS Listening on %s\n", "api.my-domain.com")
    return http.Serve(autocert.NewListener("api.my-domain.com"), handler)
}
```

[autocert.NewListener("api.my-domain.com")](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert#example-NewListener) directly fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Options

1. Instead of using a self-signed cert, use [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to generate a free cert that is considered valid because it has a backing Certificate Authority.
2. If your cert is secure enough for your purposes, add it to your client (browser) as a root CA. No one else will be able to connect to the API without doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

This line should have error checking:

```
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair( ".certificates/my-domain.crt", ".certificates/my-domain.key" )
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("key-pair error: %v", err)
}
```

While it may work locally, you can't be sure it also works in your Docker container.

Are those key/cert files available? If not - and without error checking - you are effectively passing a nil cert to your TLS config which will have no effect and no other discernable error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am now checking the err, but I have no issues at all, I just have an invalid certificate and I don't get why it is invalid

Answer (score 0):

You're using a self-signed certificate, so your browser doesn't trust it -- by design. Postman is telling you this with that message, too. This isn't a go issue, which is doing precisely what you told it to do: serving your application with an insecure certificate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. So then how can I fix this? Is the way to go is to buy a certificate or should I generate it from a special source or just uploading it somewhere? Thanks :)

Comment: That's hard to get across in a single comment here, but you should start with looking up what "certificate authorities" are. You can get a free valid certificate using LetsEncrypt, or you can pay providers like DigiCert or GoDaddy.

Comment: If you're comfortable with `curl` - you can user it to do end-to-end TLS testing, explicitly including the self-signed cert as your `CA`. But yes, if you plan on this being used by client browsers (mobile devices etc.) - a third-party CA is really the supported way to go.